# SQL Query for Activity in a specific month

Tags: sql, reporting

We have people who have rentals between two specific dates, say 1/15/2013 - 2/03/2013. What I have been tasked to do, is to show an 'Active' report, on how many Active Rentals within each month. For instance, this would show up in the January count and the February count.

Any help on this would be appreciated. I have looked for similar but not have found anything. My knowledge in sql is mainly to the simple add/change/delete codes.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: How do you define active in a month?  Is your example active in both January and Feburary?

Comment: I am using SQL 2008, sorry, first time posting here. In my example it is active in both January and February. I have tried to use temp tables, but wasn't sure how even to start to go through each month to get those 30 days...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `rentals` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-03-04' AND '2013-04-04'
```

Obviously replace the table name and column names with your own... This is MySQL, you hadn't specified what DB software you are using at the time of posting.

Comment: I am using SQL 2008, sorry..but in the example, they want a monthly report, where the activity happens to be over both months, should be counted.

Answer (score 0):

The generic way to find records that are "active" between two dates would be

```
 ...
 WHERE startDate <= @periodEnd AND endDate >= @periodStart
```

Comment: I can understand the generic way, but to get the results of Jan 2013/01---12, 2013/02 - 10, 2013/03 - 13....etc, do I have to hard code each month?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find actives during each month, you need to start with a list of months and then compare them to the activity records.  Let me assume that you have a start in each month.

```
select months.yyyymm, count(*) as NumActives
from (select distinct to_char(startdate, 'yyyy-mm') as yyyymm
      from activity
     ) as months join
     activity a
     on yyyymm between to_char(a.startdate, 'yyyy-mm') and to_char(a.enddate, 'yyyy-mm')
group by months.yyyymm
```

I used the Oracle/Postgres function `to_char()` to convert the date to a year-month representation.  Other databases have other ways of accomplishing the same goal.